# Apply for two matrixes- t.test

Tags: r, apply

It looks like I cannot figure out how to do a simple code... I would like to use any of `apply` function instead of loop for `t.test` calculations. I have two matrixes:

```
data1 <- t(replicate(2000, rnorm(200,mean=6)))
data2 <- t(replicate(2000, rnorm(200,mean=5)))
```

I would like to perform `t.test` for each of the column of these matrices and extract p-values.

I tried something like that:

```
comb_data <- array(c(data1, data2), c(dim(data1), 2))
p-value_1 <- t(apply(comb_data, 2, function(x) t.test(data1[, 1], data1[, 2])$p-value))
```

What am I missing here ?

Just to make it clear what I am aiming for:

```
t.test(data1[,i], data2[,i])
```

I would like to extract p-values out of it and store as a vector.

Comment: You are trying to do a two sample t test comparing the mean of column 1 in data1 to column 1 in data2? and so on for columns 2,3,4,..?

Comment: I am trying to make a paired t-test for corresponding columns in two matrices.

Comment: Then use `sapply(1:ncol(data1),function(x) t.test(data1[,x],data2[,x])$p.value)`

Comment: This would work: `mapply(t.test, as.data.frame(data2), as.data.frame(data1),  SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli ofcourse, you can also use `as.data.frame` to do this as a `data.frame` is nothing more than a list with additional properties, so `mapply` will treat it as a list. I do like using `split` though as it is more explicit in what it does.

Comment: yeah i figured out reason for using a split there but there is more typing in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your matrices have equal dimensions, you can loop over the column indices with `sapply` and apply them to both matrices.

`sapply(1:ncol(data1),function(x) t.test(data1[,x],data2[,x])$p.value)`

Answer (score 1):

The following code splits the matrices into a list where each element contains a column, and then calls `t.test`:

```
all_t_tests = mapply(t.test, split(data1, 1:2000), split(data2, 1:2000), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Getting the `p.value` from each of them:

```
sapply(all_t_tests, '[[', 'p.value')
```

---

Setting `SIMPLIFY` to `TRUE` combines the results of `t.test` into one big data structure and not a list of `t.test` results.

```
all_t_tests = mapply(t.test, split(data1, 1:2000), split(data2, 1:2000), SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
```

Which allows for easy access to `p.value`:

```
all_t_tests['p.value',]
```